# mod_rewrite forwarding both /blog and /Blog to a php file

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get /blog and /Blog to forward to blog.php in apache using mod_rewrite.  I initially had no trouble with the /blog part, which is here:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog
RewriteCond /blog/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /blog/([0-9]+)$ /blog.php?blog=$1
RewriteRule /blog/dates/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ /blog.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3
```

I tried to get the all-case version working with RewriteMap; however, I was unsuccessful.
I then tried RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[b,B]log, and the same for the other rewrites, but no success.

If anyone can lend advice on how to get both /blog and /Blog to forward to blog.php, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flag NC for case insensitivity.

```
RewriteCond xxxxxx [NC]
RewriteRule xxxxxxx [NC]
```